# Coffeescript not working in modal window in rails with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, bootstrap-modal

I have rails controller "contacts_controller.rb" and then I have coffeescript code in contact.coffee.

I have index view where I have bootstrap modal window where I am loading new.html.erb

```
<div id="contact-modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div id="inner-contact-modal" class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have plain simple alert that executes on clicking a heading for example the code below will work with index.html.erb

```
$ -> 
  $("#contacts-title").click ->
    alert "contacts-title is clicked"
```

But whatever coffeescript code I try to run within the modal window it doesn't work.

Do I have to create separate .coffee file for _new.html.erb view or do I have to do something after loading my modal window within index.html.erb so that .coffee file can see selectors within modal window?

Comment: Does the content within the modal get loaded via an AJAX interaction, or is there when the page loads? Regardless, you will probably want to change your $(...).click call to $(document).on('click', '...', ....

Comment: modal is loaded with button click like below

    <%= link_to 'Add contact', new_client_contact_path(@client), remote:true, class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right vcenter'  %>

Comment: For example 

   $(".btn").click -> alert "blla blla blla"

works when I click a button in index.html.erb, but not when I click a button in new.html.erb which I load as modal within index.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$("body").on "click", "#contacts-title", ()->
```

As Santiago mentioned in the comment, you need to do this in your js file as you are using turbolinks,

```
ready = ()->
  $("body").on "click", "#contacts-title", ()->
    alert "contacts-title is clicked"
$(document).on 'page:load ready', ready
```

Comment: I get error: SyntaxError: [stdin]:27:40: unexpected ->

Comment: Where are you using the coffeescript code, in the erb?

Comment: My coffescript code is in app/assets/javascripts/contact.coffee, and it is working fine when I load contacts/index.html.erb but after I load new.html.erb (in modal window within index.html.erb) the code doesn't work there

Comment: I believe the correct way to save a coffeescript in rails is `contact.js.coffee`, and you should probably tie the click event after the DOM loads maybe like this `$(document).on 'page:load ready', ->`

Comment: Usually that was the case, but I don't know maybe because I installed project on Rails 4.2 it is missing .js.

Comment: Is it maybe because I call modal through "remote:true" ?